# How to extract data from file being uploaded?

Tags: workflow

I would like to process .msg files being uploaded and extract some data from them (from, to, and similar fields) to use it as file metadata.
Could I achieve this writing a custom workflow action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could do it with a custom workflow action or an event handler for the ItemAdding Event. Here is some example code in C# to read from msg-Files:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32899/Reading-an-Outlook-MSG-File-in-C
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/712072/Reading-an-Outlook-MSG-File-in-Csharp